# Laying out controls

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out the best course of action when it comes to drawing various control configurations. In my case, I'm using images as buttons and would like to create "screens" for different control configurations. Below is an example:

[image]

Basically, I'd have a layout for each configuration. Depending on which configuration the user requests, different control layouts will be used. There's only ever one configuration set loaded at any given time.

What's the general direction I should take for this? Should I just use Fragments for each configuration? I imagine I'd want to use a layout for each control configuration. Controls are **required** to be precise, so perhaps [this library](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout), in conjunction with layouts, will work for my needs?

Answer (score 1):

I would save the requested layout in `SharedPreferences` and in the `onCreate()` method get the layout id like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
int requestedLayout = prefs.getInt("requestedLayout", R.id.layout_default);
setContentView(requestedLayout);
```

**Note:** this only works if all layouts contain the same views, otherwise fragments will be better for this purpose.

Comment: I might have been a bit vague. I'm trying to to figure out the best coarse for actually laying out a configuration. Like, using a RelativeLayout or AbsoluteLayout. This will be great when it comes to actually choosing them, though.

Comment: @Omlet In that case, use a Relative Layout. It's best for most purposes. I think  AbsoluteLayout is even deprecated because it's so unflexible.